# MyNotificationService required a bean of type 'org.springframework.mail.javamail.JavaMailSender' that could not be found

Tags: java, spring-boot, environment-variables, spring-batch, jpa-annotations

I'm reading/loading environment variables from Database. Hence I do not have application.properties.

I'm getting the following error message

```
APPLICATION FAILED TO START
***************************

Description:

Parameter 0 of constructor in com.MyNotificationService required a bean of type 'org.springframework.mail.javamail.JavaMailSender' that could not be found.
    - Bean method 'mailSender' not loaded because AnyNestedCondition 0 matched 2 did not; NestedCondition on MailSenderAutoConfiguration.MailSenderCondition.JndiNameProperty @ConditionalOnProperty (spring.mail.jndi-name) did not find property 'jndi-name'; NestedCondition on MailSenderAutoConfiguration.MailSenderCondition.HostProperty @ConditionalOnProperty (spring.mail.host) did not find property 'host'


Action:

Consider revisiting the conditions above or defining a bean of type 'org.springframework.mail.javamail.JavaMailSender' in your configuration.
```

Comment: are you using _spring-boot-starter-mail_ as a dependency?

Comment: @Dirk Deyne, yes I'm using                                                                                            
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-mail</artifactId>
</dependency>

Comment: then you should provide a ```JavaMailSender``` bean... you can configure it the way you want with your db-variables,  by using application.properties, ...

Comment: The task is to load environment variables from Database. I can not have application.properties. spring.mail.host WAS a key in application.properties.

Comment: as I have mentioned: " you can configure it the way you want "

Answer (score 0):

It seems spring could not create instance of MyNotificationService  as its constructor requires bean of type JavaMailSender.

Further down in stack you could see that its not able to find couple of properties. if you want to load properties from db could, use tutorial below

https://pure-essence.net/2011/02/10/spring-loading-properties-from-database-with-a-twist/

Comment: your example is the other way around! configure a DB via property-file

Comment: I have database.properties that has only database connection information only. spring.datasource.driver-class-name=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://test//test//database-name
spring.datasource.username=test
spring.datasource.password=test
spring.datasource.tomcat.max-active=20
spring.datasource.tomcat.initialSize=20
spring.datasource.tomcat.maxIdle=20

Comment: @tsingh the link you shared as a solution is from 2011. I'm using JPA Annotations to define my beans. I'm not using xml configuration to define my bean.s